# Python PermissionError: [WinError 32] The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process: mp4 file

Tags: python

Im currently getting this error
PermissionError: [WinError 32] The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process: 'smallvideos/file1.mp4'

I have tried different ways to close the file but without luck, no idea what I'm doing wrong here.

```
def create_file(today):
list_of_clips = []

with open("video_names.txt") as clip_file:
    read_file = clip_file.read()
    lines = read_file.splitlines()

clip_file = open("video_names.txt")

for line in lines:
    #Creates video in 720p - keeps original aspect ratio
    video = VideoFileClip(line, target_resolution=(720, None))
    list_of_clips.append(video)

    os.remove(line)

filename = "combinedVideo_" + str(today) + ".mp4"

final_clip = concatenate_videoclips(list_of_clips, method='compose')
final_clip.write_videofile(filename)

return filename
```

Answer (score -1):

This is basically permission error, you just need to close the file before removing it. After getting the file size info.

clip_file.close()

Comment: the file is not released thus mp4 file is still used by another process which in turn raises the second error.

 see this link https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/...e-handling, hope this will help.